# Too many highlighted areas in Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

New to Android studio and tried out writing some lines for my assignments. But I have noticed that there are too many highlighted areas which I have no idea what they are for since my approach to the assignments seemed correct. I have attached a photo for easy reference, hope someone can clarify.

[image: IDE warnings]

Comment: You don't need an image. Hover your mouse over the highlighted area and it should tell you or put your cursor on it and press alt + enter.

Comment: i did the hovering, but i couldnt understand their description. I have edited my post so you can see the image. And 2 options came out when i alt enter, what you need to do with that? thanks for the response.

Comment: When you press alt + enter it will give you options to fix whatever it's highlighting about. What are the options?

Answer (score 0):

ChiefTwoPencils already told you the solution for this

`Alt+Enter` will show you the options for fixing highlights. Try not to suppress warnings nor disable inspections, because especially your case they might have reason.

If you didn't see those highlights before you have probably disabled inspection (Lint) for those cases before updating Android Studio

On your screenshot you have basically 2 problems:

1. lines 46, 47, 48 -> `Method invocation might produce null pointer exception` variables `btnInterface`, `btnVariable`, `btnInner` might be null. You probably didn't initialized those variables (`btnInterface = <btnInterface class> findViewById(...)`)
2. lines 90 and 93 -> hardcoded strings. [Use string resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html)

Hope you are new to Android, because those are not things you should complain about

Comment: Can I say I can just ignore these 2 problems ? Definitely new to java , not only android

Comment: You'd better resolve those problems :) app crash because of NullPointerExceprion is bad as well as hardcoded strings

Comment: I did these references before i proceed with the onclick listener lines, is this what u meant by initializing the variables? (

final Button btnInner = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ButtonInner);
final Button btnInterface = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ButtonInterface);
final Button btnVariable = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ButtonVariable);

Comment: For line 90 i read through the string resource section and tried writing them but im still faced with the highlighted issue. Can u advise whether i got it right?

i wrote :  String string = getString(R.string.ListenerText);

Comment: `tvResult.setText(R.string.ListenerText);`

Comment: wait... can you share whole class? do you even extend AppCompatActivity?